# How to insert Unicode character U+2611 in gvim

Tags: vim, unicode

when I try to enter this Unicode character :☑(U+2611) in vim using the command like : `^Vu2611` (which means press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then type u2611 in **insert** mode),Vim somehow breaks it into two characters  : `&`(26) and `^Q`(11).

There's no any problem when I tried to insert other kind of characters like □ (U+a1f5).

It seems like Vim stopped its parsing immediately after `26` (which represents character '&') has been read .

So,how can I insert this kind of Unicode characters in Vim (I have tried to paste it into Vim ,it doesn't work)?
Please Help!!!

Comment: It works for me (in Terminal Vim 7.4.258 and MacVim). What version of gvim are you using. Does it work if you disable user settings (`gvim -u NONE`)

Comment: It's still not working even if I try to start the gvim with `-u NONE` option.I think it can be an encoding problem ,since when I set the encoding as `latin1`(`set enc=latin1`) , none of them (u2611 and ua1f5) could be correctly inserted.

Comment: My gvim version is 7.4

Comment: Yeah its the encoding. I believe you want the encoding as `utf8`

Comment: The point is how can I still insert this kind of Unicode characters correctly even if I will not usually use the UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Uh... I figure it out : just switch `enc` to `UTF-8` ,insert the character then switch back. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to process Unicode characters, Vim must use an `'encoding'` that is able to represent those characters. With a value of `latin1`, the mentioned character cannot be encoded (this 8-bit encoding only includes ASCII and several Western European characters, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)).

So, you need to

```
:set encoding=utf-8
```

With that, any newly created file will use that encoding, and you should be able to insert Unicode characters and write them (also with another Unicode file encoding, like `:w ++enc=ucs-2le`; but if you tried to persist as `:w ++enc=latin1`, you'd get a `CONVERSION ERROR`).